# What volcanoes are there to see in Italy?

Tags: italy, hiking, volcanoes

I would really like to see a volcano in Italy. The world-famous Vesuvius would be a good choice, but wikitravel describes it as "congested by pensioners", which is a no-go for me. There is the big Etna (>3000m) on the south, but I am not sure whether you can ascent it without a guide, which would be an another no-go.

What are another beautiful, big, hikable, off the beaten track volcanoes in Italy, that are worth visiting? By beautiful I mean a lot of wild nature and that the rocks should expose their volcanic origin. It should feel like a volcano, not like just one another mountain, shouldn't it?

Comment: Note that Etna is the only Volcano in Italy that meets you height criterium: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcanoes_in_Italy

Comment: Yes, I should probably edit the question. The relative height should matter..

Comment: It is really worth going with a guide.  You'll be able to see a lot more.  Why is it a "no go"?

Answer (score 3):

After Etna and Vesuvius, [Stromboli](http://www.stromboliguide.it/) is one of the most famous. Its altitude is only 924m though, below your 1500m requirement.

Comment: Never mind, it looks good. However a bit far in the see :)